# How to pass JobParams to other beans in xml?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-el

There are two job params filePath & fileName for my spring batch job. Requirement is to pass this filePath+fileName to other custom bean as a property value. However, I cannot "step" scope that bean to access these params. Hence I need a way to access these job params from (non-step) normal bean. Pls refere below code ::

```
<bean id="cardDownloadFileTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="sftpSessionFactory" />
    <property name="fileNameExpression">
        <bean class="org.springframework.expression.common.LiteralExpression">
            <constructor-arg
                value="#{jobParameters['filePath']}#{jobParameters['fileName']}}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="charset" value="${fserver.charset}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I cannot step scope since it errors out saying there is no such constructor & LiteralExpression cannot be stepScope targeted.

Comment: did you try to make the fileNameExpression Bean a first citizen by pulling it out as "real" bean with id? right now it is an anonymous inner bean

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done; for normally-scoped beans (singleton, prototype) the bean is initialized with the context, before the job is launched; there is no `jobParameters` variable available.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the normal beans as Step Listeners, and then implement the @BeforeStep method which can extract the JobParameters from the step execution.

In this case the value for the parameter you are extracting will not be available at bean initialization but will be able just before  the step starts to run.

Initialize the state of the listener with the StepExecution from the current scope
beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution)
stepExecution --> getJobParameters()

Comment: By that time , LiteralExpression is already initialized & the value( JobParams) i need is a constructor argument. So even though I get jobParams in listener, how do I pass it to constructor of fileNameExpression class ?

Comment: Right, in the case above you can't do it unless you can move the code to create LiteralExpression in either a BeforeStep or BeforeJob